# Shk shk noise when engaging clutch

Tags: transmission, clutch

I have noticed when clutch is engaged there is a sound(not sure how to describe it but it sounds something like she shk shk shk shk repeatedly and fast.  when I put the clutch down
/disengage it the sounds disappears but comes when I engage it again.

It may also be occluding when driving but not sure.

Any idea what the problem may be.

Thanks

Comment: Does "put the clutch down" mean you are pressing the clutch pedal? Remember, pressing the pedal is disengaging the clutch. Lifting your foot up off the clutch pedal is engaging the clutch.

Comment: @paulster2 yes I meant the sound happens when I engage the clutch and disengaging removes the sound.

Comment: @JamesWilson Just to clarify, are you saying that when you are in the process of changing gears, you don't hear the sound. But when you've completed the gear change and driving steadily, you hear the sound?

Comment: @JamesWilson Just trying to avoid confusion here because IF the sound occurs when you put your foot down to disengage the clutch and change gears, I would suggest its the thrust bearing.
If its the opposite of that, the answer will be different.

Comment: @NetServeOps It’s the opposite so not the thrust bearing.

Comment: @JamesWilson If the sound is repeated and fast, that would suggest its being made by a part that rotates.
So, does the rate of 'shk shk' increase as the vehicle speed increases?